# i am trying to insert data .csv file on database l it will be show header as a column records?

Tags: mysql, import, phpmyadmin

when i am trying to insert data .csv file to database on go-daddy c panel which is on phpmyadmin it will be show header as a column records. I need to import that file to the database. My problem comes when I need the full solution.

The CSV has 5 fields, the user table has 5 fields.
when the import of data is completed it show header in the column but i am never use header in .csv file.

Comment: You have to be more specific when asking a question, give concrete code examples so that everybody understands what exactly is your problem. More info you provide, the better chance for an answer you get.

Answer (score 1):

Although the requirement is not very clear in the question (please add some example of data and what you tried) but as per my understanding.. Create the required table in the database and then execute the statement below. This should do the trick.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE "/path/to/file.csv"
INTO TABLE MYTABLE 
COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```